# text alignment ckeditor

Tags: css, button, ckeditor, text-align

I can't find how to add a button to format my text:

```
text-align:center;
text-align:left;
text-align:right;
text-align:justify;
```

I have the v4 version

http://ckeditor.com/demo

I try to find a solution but I just find some issue posts.

Maybe using a plugin ?

I'm using ckEditor like that forexemple:

```
<textarea id="monday" class="ckeditor" name="monday" ><?php echo $this->datas['monday']; ?></textarea>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is an option to use the Full Featured instead of the Standard editor?

Answer (score 5):

You just have to add justification to your configuration -- e.g.,

```
var config = {
    toolbar: [
        ['Font','FontSize'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
        ['TextColor','BGColor'],
        ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight']
    ],
};
$('.ckeditor').ckeditor(config);
```

Comment: I am looking justify, not left/center/right align. Any suggestion to justify the contents in ckeditor?? Thanks.

Comment: Use 'JustifyBlock' to justify the contents